# Change regex delimiter in awk patterns

Tags: regex, awk, gawk, nawk

Is is possible to change the default regex delimiter (slash) to other characters?

I tried to do it using with **sed** syntax but it didn't work.

```
$ gawk '\|bash| { print } ' backup.sh
gawk: |bash| { print }
gawk: ^ syntax error
```

The regex I am trying has many slashes. Escaping all of them will make it ugly and unreadable. I tried changing the / to | but it didn't work.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWK doesn't support that. Use a variable instead.

```
gawk 'BEGIN {pattern = "/"} $0 ~ pattern {print}' backup.sh
```

Comment: I am trying to use this example when extracting lines between 2 patterns, eg `awk '/pat1/,/pat2/' foo.html` -- patterns contain both slashes and double quote chars (it is html code).  Can you provide an example showing to do this without having to escape the slashes and double quotes?

Comment: @JonathanCross it's not possible without doing some escaping somewhere. You may need to create a new question showing the specific issues you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps you can show how `awk '/pat1/,/pat2/' foo.html` would be adapted to use 2 vars instead of `/pat1/` and `/pat2/` -- and then I can figure out the escaping?

Comment: @JonathanCross: `awk 'BEGIN {var1 = "pat1"; var2 = "pat2"} $0 ~ var1, $0 ~ var2 {print}' filename` is one way. Another: `awk -v var1='pat1' -v var2='pat2' '$0 ~ var1, $0 ~ var2 {print}' filename` is another (which allows you to pass in shell variables as well as the strings/patterns shown).